# Sum array of inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-filter

I have a list of data which when I make the bind I have to call a funcion on keypress event of input (I made my code in angular with this fiddle):

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in Data">
            <input ng-model="item.Value" ng-keydown="Total()" />

            </li>
        </ul>
      Total: {{TheTotal}}
  </div>
</div>
```

**ANGULAR**

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.Data = [
    {
        Value: 1
    },
    {
        Value: 2
    }];
    $scope.TheTotal= 0;
    $scope.Total = function()
    {
        var returnValue = 0;
        $scope.TheTotal  = 0;       

        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.Data.length; i++)
        {
            returnValue = returnValue + parseInt($scope.Data[i].Value);                  
        }

        $scope.TheTotal =  returnValue;        
    };
}
```

But what I need is when the value of input changes, then makes the summatory but it is failing because always lost the last key pressed ... Any help ??

Here is the fiddler: [Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/fcastelblanco/ygkhh5q5/)

Comment: you could make it more cleaner using filter rather than putting it inside controller

Comment: Your code works as-is. http://jsfiddle.net/ygkhh5q5/9/

Comment: so you comment on my post that passing data inside sum isn't neccesary but in your fiddle you do it anyways. also his code works as is? why is his total function changed to sum?

Comment: The question is unclear, fiddle doesn't match code in question. His code in the question would work, but, it's going to be behind one letter due to the event being used.

Comment: @KevinB But ... Well, the trouble was that I must not use the ng-keypress event ... But the questios is according with the code ... The other comments helps me to locate the code for works fine ... Any way thanks for the suggestion ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [This thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109075/angular-sum-of-input-values-not-updating)

the following will do the trick: http://jsfiddle.net/ygkhh5q5/6/

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in Data">
            <input ng-model="item.Value" />

            </li>
        </ul>
      Total: {{sum(Data)}}
  </div>
</div>

function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.Data = [
    {
        Value: 1
    },
    {
        Value: 2
    }];
    $scope.sum = function(list) {
      var total=0;
      angular.forEach(list , function(item){
        total+= parseInt(item.Value);
      });
      return total;
     }
}
```

Comment: Why switch to using `sum(Data)` outside of an `ng-<event>` when what he is currently using works and will result in `sum()` being executed less often?

Comment: @KevinB good point..passing `Data` inside some is not appropriate

Comment: Well, the problem for those who want to answer is that OP's fiddle example has different code from what is posted in the question.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't notice the discrepancy in the fiddle either.

Answer (score 2):

Not an unique answer but for code reusability I'll create it as filter so that any other can take use of it

**Markup**

```
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in Data">
            <input ng-model="item.Value"/>
        </li>
        </ul>
      Total: {{Data | total: 'Value'}}
  </div>

</body>
```

**Code**

```
.filter('total', function(){
  return function(array, prop){
    var total = 0;
    angular.forEach(array, function(value){
      total = total + parseInt(value[prop]);
    })
    return total;
  }
})
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/BZGAklu49155P7723TRX?p=preview)

Comment: Nice. very elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

The event you are using to update the total is triggering before the value of the input has actually changed. You should instead either use the keyup event, or the change event.

http://jsfiddle.net/ygkhh5q5/12/

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in Data">
            <input ng-model="item.Value" ng-change="Total()" />

            </li>
        </ul>
      Total: {{TheTotal}}
  </div>
</div>
```