# How should I bind values of an object inside an ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a complex object that I wish to display and edit in my page.

More specifically for my actual case, I have an object that has a `<string, array>` pair, where `array` is actually a collection of objects with various `<string, int>` pairs.

I try to iterate over this complex structure like this:

```
      <div data-ng-repeat="(key, table) in TestData">
            <h3>{{key}}</h3>

            <table class="responsive-table">                    
                <tbody>
                    <tr data-ng-repeat="row in table">
                        <td data-ng-repeat="(label, value) in row" data-title="label">
                            <div>
                                <input data-ng-model="TestData[key][?][label]" data-ng-readonly="isEditable(label)" data-ng-change="show()" />                                    
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>
```

There seems to be no way for me to find what value I should use in my model because I cant get my exact item in the structure inside the second repeat.

Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binding inputs to an array of primitives using ngRepeat => uneditable inputs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488342/binding-inputs-to-an-array-of-primitives-using-ngrepeat-uneditable-inputs)

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite the `show()` function:

```
$scope.show= function (row) {
   console.log("Test: ", row);
}
```

and change the `ngChange`-Handler to `data-ng-change="show(row);`. This way, you can update your model in the show-function.

Answer (score 2):

You should not bind directly to primitives. What you can do is use `$index` to bind to the array item instead:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in test track by $index">
   <input data-ng-model="test[$index]" data-ng-change="show()" />
</div>
```

Comment: Also, this question seems to be a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488342/binding-inputs-to-an-array-of-primitives-using-ngrepeat-uneditable-inputs

Comment: It quite probably is a duplicate. Let me edit it and make it more specific.

Comment: edited to reflect my actual problem, I should have typed that from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the ng-repeat there exists an own scope you can use

```
$scope.show= function () {
   console.log("Test: ", $scope.$parent.test);
};
```

to receive the result you expect