# ng-repeat second running index, separate from $index

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm looking for a way to present a running index which ios consistent but does not run on all repeat instances.

```
<div class="cell" ng-repeat="c in arr">
    <div ng-if="c !== false">{{    <someIndex>   }}</div>
</div>
```

Assuming `arr = ['word-y', false, false, 'word-x', 'word-z', false, ...]`, Some of the cells will have an inner value displayed, and some won't.

I'm interested in showing a running count so that the first cell will show `1`, the second and third naturally empty, and the **fourth** will show `2`, and so on (this is why `$index` is of no use to me).

Notes:

1. The array on which the values are calculated must be able to change after first calculation, and values will the re-calculate.
2. I currently do not use jQuery in this project, and if possible I would like to keep it that way.

Comment: Your array objects change over time? those that are false may become objects?

Comment: @AranS - Yes. Those that are false might become objects, and vice-versa, some may become false after having a value.

Comment: I'm not sure you can avoid $watching in this case. I suggest mapping your array in each change. I can give an example if you need.

Comment: Thanks, I think @Piyush.kapoor has provided enough of an example of a map. :)

Answer (score 1):

Keep another array in your scope whose value would be number if the entry is not false

```
$scope.runningCount = [ 1, -1,-1,3,4,...]
```

Now inside your html use ng-repeat index to display the correct text/count

```
<div class="cell" ng-repeat="c in arr">
    <div ng-if="c !== false">{{   runningCount[{{index}}   }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution is legit, though not very scalable, the second array will still need to be regenerated using either a `$scope.watch()` or another event, and will require a manual loop. I'm interested in avoiding that and letting angular do the work for me.

Comment: hmmm Angular dont have any filter to convert $index into some other index

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

Thne problem is you are losing the refence. You can do that with a single array. You need a array of objects.

You have a nice explanation of this issue here:
[Binding inputs to an array of primitives using ngRepeat => uneditable inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488342/binding-inputs-to-an-array-of-primitives-using-ngrepeat-uneditable-inputs)

Then you can try any of the other solutions I propose to you, for example:

```
$scope.arr  = [{value: 'word-y'}, {value:'sd'}, {value:false}, {value:'word-x'}, {value:'word-z'}];
```

and:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .list-cell {
    counter-reset: cell;
 }
.cell_iter:before {
    counter-increment: cell;
    content: "position " counter(cell) ". ";
 }

</style>
```

[..]

```
  <ul  class="list-cell">
    <li  ng-repeat="c in arr track by $index">
      <span ng-class="{'cell_iter': c.value !== false}">{{ c.value }}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

An example here: https://plnkr.co/edit/z0d27M8otjc16THMUPkA

**OLD Reply**
The posible solutions:

(Solution 1)In your controller modify the array in order to have the index value:

```
var newArr = arr.filter(function(value){return value!== false})
```

(Solution 2) Or in your template:

```
<div class="cell" ng-repeat="c in arr | filter:filterFn">
```

And in yout controller:

```
 $scope.filterFn = function(c){ return c !== false}
```

(Solution 3) The solution that I most like, only css:

```
<div class="list-cell"> 
    <div class="cell" ng-repeat="c in arr">
        <div class="cell_iter" ng-if="c !== false">{{    <someIndex>   }}</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.list-cell {
    counter-reset: cell;
 }
.cell_iter:before {
    counter-increment: cell;
    content: "position " counter(cell) ". ";
 }
```

(Other solutions) You can play with ng-init in your ng-repeat. Create a new variable... But this solution will be ugly.

**UPDATE ADDING NG-INIT:**

the idea is to create a new property in the parent context to ng-repeat and inside the ng-repeat another different context.

We will do all this in the template (Ugly):

```
  <ul class="example-animate-container"  ng-init="$counterHelper=0">
    <li class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="c in arr track by $index" ng-init="$parent.$counterHelper = c !== false?$counterHelper +1:$counterHelper; p={}; p.value=c; p.$counter = $counterHelper;">
      [{{$index + 1}}] [{{ p.$counter }}] {{ p.value }} 
    </li>
  </ul>
```

here an example: https://plnkr.co/edit/z0d27M8otjc16THMUPkA?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 1,2 aren't relevant, as I don't want to filter out the empty divs, I gave a simplified example, but the use case is more complex, and they do contain other elements. I will try No. 3.

Comment: Okay, that doesn't cover my use case as well. Would you mind sharing the `ng-init` option as well?

Comment: @CommonRaven  I update the reply with ng-init. I think is an interesting thing to show.

Comment: Thank you so much for your efforts, very disappointed to say ng-init won't do the trick for an update of the data (question note 1). I have forked your plunker and added a setTimeout in the controller which changes the data.
https://plnkr.co/edit/DrqmcuhJ8dxa4IjcU9OI

Comment: @CommonRaven With the example is easy to understand the problem. I update the reply

Comment: any luck? @CommonRaven

Comment: Nope, currently, as an intermediate solution I'm mapping my array to another and using the second one for the running index, but I'm not pleased with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a simple and elegant solution by just using an [angular filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) to "filter out" the falsey elements in the array, for example, try this:

```
<div class="cell" ng-repeat="c in $ctrl.arr | filter: '!false' track by $index">
    <div>{{ c }} {{ $index }}</div>
</div>
```

(note you don't actually need the `ng-if` anymore!)

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this does not work with my use case, as I don't want to filter out the empty divs, I gave a simplified example, but the use case is more complex, and they do contain other elements..