# ng-repeat inputs losing function losing focus

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

http://plnkr.co/edit/g89wEeG30sOXhgzHWX0Z?p=preview

I've been reading about this and the consensus seems to be that this issue when binding to primitives was resolved in 1.1.2*, yet my problem persists. Maybe I'm using the repeater incorrectly? **Please note that I am unable to change the data-structure.**

I'm open to any work-arounds or creative hacks. So far, the only thing I've been able get working correctly was using this version of angular:
http://ci.angularjs.org/job/angular.js-pete/12/artifact/build/angular.js

But I dont think it's going to be patched in any time soon. Thoughts?

*
[Difficulty with ng-model, ng-repeat, and inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13714884/difficulty-with-ng-model-ng-repeat-and-inputs)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use the new ngRepeat syntax (introduced in 1.1.x) and use `track by $index`:

```
<td ng-repeat="point in series.data  track by $index">
  <input type="number"  ng-model="series.data[$index]" />
</td>
```

Working plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/CEwr2GJ4YrS5H7yBOKJn?p=preview

More info [here](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.directive:ngRepeat)

Comment: Thanks- I'd read that documentation but didnt make the connection with 'track by'. I've read it again and Im still not sure I get it :\

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource can you explain why `track by $index` is a necessity for a resolution of the problem? - It will make your answer more useful and solid. Thanks.

Comment: The reason "track by" works here is because AngularJS will default to tracking by value when you have an array of primitives (an array of strings, for instance). When you change the values, the old elements are removed from the DOM and new elements are added, causing the loss of focus. When you track by $index, the DOM is not effected unless you change the order of the items, effectively changing their index.