# Changing text model value doesn't reflect in the scope array

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to angular and I have input fields populated with data. But on data change on input field it is not getting reflected in the array present in the scope.

JS

```
var app = angular.module('plunker',[]);
app.controller('Nav', function($scope) {
      $scope.urls = [
          "http://google.com",
          "http://cnn.com"  
     ]; 
});
```

HTML

```
<body ng-controller="Nav">
    {{urls}}
    <div ng-repeat="url in urls">
        <input type="text" ng-model="url" />
    </div> 
</body>
```

Demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/OXXdFK2JElVaAh0uYmxG?p=preview

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difficulty with ng-model, ng-repeat, and inputs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13714884/difficulty-with-ng-model-ng-repeat-and-inputs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values in the scope do not change because you are not binding to an object. If you change the initial array like this:

```
$scope.urls = [
    { url: "http://google.com" },
    { url: "http://cnn.com" }  
];
```

and update the `ng-repeat` to `item in urls` and `ng-model` to `item.url`, everything should work as expected.

In your example, the `url` reffered to a `string` and angular was unable to properly resolve the binding.

Please see my updated demo:
http://plnkr.co/edit/plrJQHZdZ9sa45ypO29N?p=preview