# Get object property which fired the $watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When you're using a $watch method (with equality by value). Is there a way to see which object property was changed?

e.g.

```
/**
                 * Save state of button: Cancelled
                 */
                $scope.$watch('buttons.cancelled', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                    if(newValue != oldValue && newValue !== undefined)  {
                        privates.viewState.buttons.cancelled = $scope.buttons.cancelled;
                    }
                });

                /**
                 * Save state of button: Booked
                 */
                $scope.$watch('buttons.booked', function(newValue, oldValue)    {
                    if(newValue != oldValue && newValue !== undefined)  {
                        privates.viewState.buttons.booked = $scope.buttons.booked;
                    }
                });
```

Turned into;

```
        $scope.$watch('buttons', function(newValue, oldValue)   {
            if(newValue != oldValue && newValue !== undefined)  {
                //Is there a way to know which button triggered this watch?
            }
        }, true);
```

Comment: Well, you have the `newValue` and `oldValue` so you got to do the comparison yourself (`if(newValue.booked !== oldValue.booked){'booked changed!'}`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an [example](http://jsbin.com/UzOreToC/2/edit).

**I would also like to see an angular built-in feature but as for now You need to do that manually**

I put the buttons inside **array of objects** rather than in hash keys because:

- Hash keys are harder to iterate and transform.
- I use **ng-model** ([Difficulty with ng-model, ng-repeat, and inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13714884/difficulty-with-ng-model-ng-repeat-and-inputs))

#### $watch is invoked with *new Value* and *old Value*, just compare them :

```
$scope.buttons = [
  { name: 'cancelled', checked: false},
  { name: 'booked', checked: false},
  { name: 'something', checked: false}
];

$scope.$watch('buttons',function(newVal,oldVal){
  oldVal = oldVal.reduce(function(p,k){ p[k.name] = k.checked; return p;},{});

  var changed = newVal.filter(function(k){ 
    return oldVal[k.name] !== k.checked;
  });

  changed = changed.reduce(function(p,k){ p[k.name] = k.checked; return p;},{});

 $scope.changed = changed;

},true);
```