# Angularjs checkbox ng-model not working

Tags: angularjs

Here is the [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/9XVekg?p=preview).

What I am trying to do is when `Option1` is clicked, the Answer Object will show:
`{"Untitle Title": Option1}`, then if `Option2` is click, it will add `Option2` value.

Here my problem is, when `Option1` or `Option2` is clicked, the other is clicked as well. and the print object is: `{"Untitle Title": true}`, but what I want is `{"Untitle Title": Option1}`

Could someone help me on that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difficulty with ng-model, ng-repeat, and inputs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13714884/difficulty-with-ng-model-ng-repeat-and-inputs)

Comment: I see that you are using `ng-model` inside a `ng-repeat`, you might want to check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13714884/difficulty-with-ng-model-ng-repeat-and-inputs

Comment: Each checkbox is bound to the same model value: ng-model="answer[data.Question.title[lang]]" (lang is constant) which would explain why clicking on one checkbox affects the other. As you're using checkboxes, the answer object with a key of the question title won't work as the keys need to be unique.

Comment: @GruffBunny hmm... i think so, so what you recommend to do? change the object structure?