# 2-way binding to values in ng-repeat tags

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array of headers for my table, I want these headers to be editable:

```
$scope.headers = ['header 1', 'header 2', 'header 3'];
```

In my view I display them like so:

```
<table data-ng-show="showData">
    <tr>
        <th data-ng-repeat="h in headers">
            <input type="text" data-ng-model="h" required/>
        </th>
    </tr>
<!-- data here -->
</table>
```

They indeed are being displayed (text boxes have appropriate text inside). However, if I edit any of the textboxes, the values in $scope.headers do not change. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: `data-ng-model="headers[$index]"` works but the textboxes loose focus on key up.

Comment: OK I found why that happens: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13714884/difficulty-with-ng-model-ng-repeat-and-inputs

Comment: thanks, solved it with using objects :) Still why there is no binding to primitives is beyond my comprehension. Surely this is a very popular use case...

Comment: @DanielGruszczyk primitives in JS are passed by value, objects by reference. If you pass a value to a function, it has no way of telling where it came from, but changing a passed object will cause it to change for whatever called the function as well. The point of isolate scopes (such as the scopes created for each repetition of `ngRepeat`) is to have them not depend whatsoever on their parent scopes, so without passing an object by reference, they can't cause changes in the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We dont need to use index, a simple ng-model will do the trick if you change your model to include attributes.

Code Snippet:

Controller Code:

```
function cntrl($scope){
    console.log("hi");
    $scope.headers = [{head:'header 1'}, {head:'header 2'}, {head:'header 3'}];
}
```

Template:

```
<div ng-app>
<div ng-controller="cntrl">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="h in headers">
            <input ng-model="h.head" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="h in headers">
            {{h.head}}
        </td>
    </tr>
<!-- data here -->
</table>
 </div>
</div>
```

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rLPJL/)

Answer (score 0):

Whatever it is you are binding has to be an object (or an array because I'm lazy). That's how to get the two-way binding to work. You can do it as mentioned in the comments, or like this, for example:

JS:

```
$scope.headers = [['header 1'], ['header 2'], ['header 3']];
```

HTML:

```
<th data-ng-repeat="h in headers">
     <input type="text" data-ng-model="h[0]"></input>
</th>
```