# Input blurs on change

Tags: angularjs

I'm rendering a list of items to allow their editing and I'm saving the changes immediately to back-end. I'm using the following code:

```
<div ng-repeat="person in people">
    <label>{{person.name}}</label>
    <input type="number" ng-model="person.age" ng-change="person.save()" ng-disabled="person.saving" >
</div>
```

and the input blurs each time I edit the value (see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1740hzjb/1/)).

The [only similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13714884/difficulty-with-ng-model-ng-repeat-and-inputs) I was able to find on SO didn't help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was in disabling the input while saving to back-end. **Each time the input is disabled, it loses focus.** So, even though the saving took such a short time that I couldn't see the input being disabled and enabled again, I could observe the resulting blur.