# binding data in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have this simple controller in app.js

```
var app = angular.module('graphPlotterDemoApp', []);

app.controller('PlotCtrl1', function ($scope) {
    $scope.data = [{
        x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
        y: [10, 15, 12, 17]}];
});
```

And I am trying to bind this to a table ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="graphPlotterDemoApp">

before div = PlotCtrl1
<div  ng-controller="PlotCtrl1">
    {{data}}
    <table>
    <thead><tr><td>x</td><td>y</td></tr></thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat='x1 in data[0].x'>
        <tr>
            <td><input type='number' ng-model='x1'></td>
            <td><input type='number' ng-model='data[0].y[$index]'></td>
        </tr>    
    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>     
</body>
</html>
```

It turns out that there is two-way data binding for `ng-model='data[0].y[$index]` but not for `ng-model='x1'` !

Anyone knows the reason for this??

Comment: here is well [explained answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13723990/2435473)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this page in the wiki.
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#ng-repeat

It's all about understanding the difference between objects and primitives when using Angular Scoping.

Comment: Thanks! Thats a great article!

Answer (score 2):

ssm, The data being bound to the `$scope` is `data`, right? Unfortunately, you are re-binding a sub-set of `data` which creates an isolated scope for that specific instance of ng-model. You are trying to bind a new value to the $scope when there was none. It's not the same as saying, `ng-model="data"`, or `data[0].y[$index]` where you would be directly referring to the original data structure.