# How to use one model in ng-repeat using AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs

This is my Fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/0c5p38dt/1/

In the above fiddle use ng-model in textfield and add save button

```
<input type="text" ng-model="eachItem.value"/>
<input type="button" value="save" ng-click="save()"/>
```

and i write code in js file :-

```
$scope.save=function(){
   console.log($scope.data);
};
```

In the above code first i click add button when i enter data in first textfield(name) that will also effect on second textfield(name). I want to save the data . So how to differentiate these textboxes.

Comment: Can you elaborate more what you want to achieve?

Comment: Don't bind to primitives. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13714884/difficulty-with-ng-model-ng-repeat-and-inputs and https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1267. However you can achieve by this. https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:8rFfZljYNl3z1A4LKSL2?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

you should use a 'name' attribute in your input fields with angular

`$index`
 on `ng-repeat`.

**in your Fiddle:**

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="eachItem in data">
      <input type="button" value="add" ng-click="addFields(eachItem)"/>
      <label>{{eachItem.label}}</label>
      <input type="text" name="eachItem.label[$index]" />
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**The result would be like:**

```
<input type="text" name="email[1]"> 
<input type="text" name="email[2]"> 
<input type="text" name="email[3]"> 
<input type="text" name="name[1]"> 
<input type="text" name="name[2]">
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you want, but I don't think you want the `<input>` in an ng-repeat, maybe what you want is in your `.html`:

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text"ng-model="item.name"/>
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="text"ng-model="item.email"/>
    <input type="button" value="add" ng-click="addFields(item)"/>
    <div ng-repeat="item in data">
       <div ng-bind="item.name"></div>
       <div ng-bind="item.email"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and in your `.js`:

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
   $scope.data=[];
   $scope.addFields = function (item) {
      $scope.data.push(item);
   };
}
```

This will give you the inputs once and then keep track (and display) the data from the inputs