# Not able to retrieve value of ng-model(Used with ng-repeat)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Being new in angular js ,just trying some basic example & came across this issue.

I am creating a table using `ng-repeat` where a `json array` is the data source. The table has a quantity column and an add button.

I want to increase the value of quantity once I click on the add button.By understanding is since it is a two way data binding if I increase the value bind to `ng-model` it will reflect in the view, *which is not happening*

**JS**

```
angular.module('DemoApp',[]).controller('TableController',['$scope',function($scope){
  $scope.dataset = [json data ];
      $scope.add = function($event){
        // get $scope.bookQuantity,add 1
        var _m =$scope.bookQuantity;
        console.log(_m) // consoling undefined;
      }
    }])
```

I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13714884/difficulty-with-ng-model-ng-repeat-and-inputs) but still not able to resolve the issue.

I have created this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/MtnFllTBu9hfFomgOjpJ?p=preview) which may help to understand the problem.

Comment: There is no `bookQuantity` in `$scope`

Comment: `tr` is not closed..

Comment: In broader scene the question is how do I get the bookQuantity? I am binding ng-model=data.bookQuantity. Have also closed the tr and have updated the link

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/tkzmrhdq/2/

Comment: What exactly, do you think, should happen when you add `ng-model` to a table cell?

Answer (score 1):

try like this. you should change your solution for this. i pass `bookId` as parameter to function and when action do it plus bookQuantity field in array.

```js
// Code goes here

angular.module('DemoApp',[]).controller('TableController',['$scope',function($scope){
  
  $scope.dataset = [{
bookId: "1001",
bookName: "Wings",
bookPrice: 224,
bookQuantity: 4
    },{
bookId: "1002",
bookName: "Turning",
bookPrice: 142,
bookQuantity: 3
},{
bookId: "1003",
bookName: "Playing",
bookPrice: 402,
bookQuantity: 2
},{
bookId: "1004",
bookName: "Steve Jobs",
bookPrice: 418,
bookQuantity: 2},{
bookId: "1005",
bookName: "History",
bookPrice: 207,
bookQuantity: 2
}]
  
  $scope.add = function(bookId){
    angular.forEach( $scope.dataset,function(item){
      
        if(item.bookId == bookId)
          item.bookQuantity = item.bookQuantity + 1;
      });
    
    console.log($scope.dataset);
  }
  
  
  
}])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
 <div ng-app="DemoApp" ng-controller ="TableController" >
    <table>
      <thead></thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="data in dataset">
          <td>{{data.bookId}}</td>
          <td>{{data.bookName}}</td>
          <td>{{data.bookPrice}}</td>
          <td>{{data.bookQuantity}}</td>
          <td><input type = "button" value ="Add" data-id ="{{data.bookId}}" ng-click = "add(data.bookId)"></td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
      
      
      
      </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Will it change the ng-model associated with bookQuantity & update the view?

Comment: I am up voting it since it is probably another way of resolving the issue.

Comment: any way for resolve this, it should update array. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this :-
`*.html`

```
<thead></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="data in dataset">
      <td>...</td>
      ...
      .
      <td><input type = "button" value ="Add" data-id ="{{data.bookId}}" ng-click = "add(data)"></td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
```

`*.js`

```
$scope.add = function(record){
   record.bookQuantity  = record.bookQuantity + 1;
   console.log(record.bookQuantity); // consoling not undefined;
}
```