# AngularJS creating json from ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ionic-framework

Inspired from this [codepen](http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/tfAzj?editors=1010) I used a `JSON file` to load some basic input fields and toggles. When the user change something and press save, I would like to save these new `property values` in a new `JSON object` with same `property names`.

My code looks the this

**JS**

```
.controller('page', function($scope, templateSettingsFactory, savedSettingsFactory) {
  $scope.template = templateSettingsFactory;    
  $scope.saved = savedSettingsFactory;    
  $scope.saveSettings = function(){                                  
                              var temp = $scope.template;
                              var jsonObj = {};
                              for(var key in temp){
                                jsonObj[key]=temp[key];
                              }
                              $scope.saved.$add(jsonObj);
                        };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<label ng-repeat="item in template">
     <input type="text" placeholder="{{item}}">
</label>

<button class="button" ng-click="saveSettings()">Save</button>
```

The problem is that calling the `saveSettings()` don't get the updated `property values` of `$scope.template` - perhaps it's not doing two-way binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `ng-model` on your form elements to bind their input to the scope.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="item.property">
```

Here is an example of binding to a single object with arbitrary keys:

```
  <div ng-repeat="(key,value) in template">
    <div>{{key}}</div>
   <input type="text" ng-model="template[key]"/>
  </div>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel

Comment: It really all depends on your json input. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13715352/580487

Comment: it's not an array of objects that my ng-repeat loops through, it's just all the property names in the object and their values.

Comment: i've updated my example to show binding to one object with arbitrary keys

Comment: The `(key, value in template` seems to work... but have a strange behavior of making the placeholder the actual input value

Comment: Thank you very much for the swift answer