# Taking user in put in a Controller Array

Tags: angularjs

I am new with Angularjs. I want to take user input in my array of the controller

This is the html

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
             <h4> data A:</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
             <h4><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="a"></h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <h4>data B:</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <h4><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="b"></h4>
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row btn-primary text-center" ng-click="showData()">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open" aria-hidden="true">
            <h4>data</h4>
        </i>
    </div>
```

and the controller

```
 $scope.infoSet =[
                {
                 "key" : "data A",
                 "value" : $scope.a
             },
             {
                 "key" : "data B",
                  "value" : $scope.b
             }];

 $scope.showData = function () {
    console.log($scope.infoSet);
    console.log($scope.a);
    console.log($scope.b);
}
```

How can i do that ? i have tried [Difficulty with ng-model, ng-repeat, and inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13714884/difficulty-with-ng-model-ng-repeat-and-inputs) . 
But i cant put the input in proper format with this. please help . thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly isn't working for you?  At a glance, it looks like what you have setup will update `$scope.a` and `$scope.b`, but not `$scope.infoSet` as it is setting `value` equal to primitive values on `a` and `b`, not the objects themselves.

Comment: yes . Thank you so much for pointing it out. i guess i was making this mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `$scope.a` and `$scope.b`, and use

```
ng-model="infoSet[0].value"
```

and

```
ng-model="infoSet[1].value"
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use ng-repeat

```
<div class="row text-center" ng-repeat="info in infoSet">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
         <h4>{{info.key}}</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
         <h4><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="info.value"></h4>
    </div>
</div>
```