# How To Access Loop Variables in Angular NgRepeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How can I do `console.log(childResult)` in the code below? In general where/how can I learn how to access ngRepeat scope(s) variables... NOT those in respective controller (it seems easy)... but esp I want to access the LOOP VARIABLES e.g. `childResult` in my case. I have read all the guides and tutorials incl stackoverflow questions but I just cannot resolve it.

```
app.directive("appNamesTyped", ['$http', '$timeout', function ($http, $timeout) {
    //app-names-typed
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: "<li ng-repeat=\"childResult in childrenLookupResults.d.as_typed | orderBy:'fname' | limitTo: limitLookupResults : beginLookupResults\"> </li>",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            try {
                console.log(childResult);
            } catch(er) {

            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Have you tried "console.log(scope.childResult)"

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do it is by using the `childrenLookupResults` object and looping through it. It would print the elements without regard to the template. Something like this

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    for(var i = 0; i < scope.childrenLookupResults.length; i++){
       console.log(scope.childrenLookupResults[i]);
    }
}
```

Here's a related question that might be helpful for you: [AngularJS: Setting a variable in a ng-repeat generated scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17828899/angularjs-setting-a-variable-in-a-ng-repeat-generated-scope)

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
   link: angular.forEach(scope.childrenLookupResults,function(childrenLookup){
          console.log(childrenLookup);
       });
```